# Solve functional equation $f(z)=c+zf(z^2)$ with series expansion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, functional-equations

Let the functional equation $(1)$ be given as

$$ f(z)=c+zf(z^2) \tag{1}$$

where $c \in\mathbb R$ and $c \neq 0$.

1. How can this functional equation be solved with series expansion (power, Taylor or Laurent)?
2. Are there any criteria for the constant $c$?

Thank you!

Comment: We can see $c$ as being $0$ given that $f(1) = c + 1 f(1)$

Thus $f(z) = z f(z^2)$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Do you mean $c=0$?

Comment: yep you were very quick on that one haha

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst But that doesn't solve the function equation anyway? I would like a solution for the functional equation in general, with $c \neq 0$.

Comment: $c$ is by definition zero, it is something we deduce from the very beginning

Comment: You are right though, we shall continue by solving $f(z) = zf(z^2)$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Okay, I don't see that $c$ must be zero? Say $c$ was 2, would the solution be the same anyway? Thanks!

Comment: Well assuming the equation is true for all $z$, then by plugging in $1$, $f(1) = f(1^2)$, so we can deduce it

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Okay, yes, that seems reasonable :) Although, let us assume $c=1$, would there be any solutions for it then?

Comment: If $c=1$ then you'd have to have $f(z) = \pm \infty$ I reckon

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Alright, interesting! Is this possible to show with a series expansion? Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that would be very important for us to know, if we're to approach this functional equation. In particular, we'd want to have some idea of the domain of definition. Without that, attempting to do a series expansion could be very misleading. I will assume herein that $f$ should be defined in a (punctured) neighborhood of $0.$

---

The results will differ if we use Laurent expansion versus Taylor expansion, since the Taylor expansion will necessarily be defined at $0,$ whereas the Laurent expansion need not be.

Let's suppose that $$f(z)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} a_n z^n,$$ so that $$zf\left(z^2\right)=z\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} a_n \left(z^2\right)^n=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}^\infty a_n z^{2n+1}.$$ Noting that we can rewrite $$f(z)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} a_{2k} z^{2k}+\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} a_{2k+1} z^{2k+1},$$ we find that $$f(z)-zf\left(z^2\right)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} a_{2k}z^{2k}+\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} (a_{2k+1}-a_k)z^{2k+1}.$$ Since we need this to be equal to $c,$ then we must have $a_0=c,$ $a_{2k}=0$ for all non-zero $k,$ and $a_{2k+1}=a_k$ for all $k.$

I claim moreover that $a_n=c$ if $n=2^j-1$ for some nonnegative integer $j$; for $n=-1,$ we cannot determine $a_n$ without more information; for all other $n,$ $a_n=0.$ Since $a_0=c$ and $a_{2n+1}=a_n$ for all $n,$ then we can easily prove by induction that $a_n=c$ whenever $n=2^j-1$ for some nonnegative integer $j.$ (I leave that to you.) Likewise, since $a_{2k}=0$ for all nonzero $k,$ then readily, $a_n=0$ whenever $n$ is a non-zero even integer, and in particular when $n=2^j$ or $n=-2^j$ for some positive integer $j.$ (Again, I leave the proof to you.) To prove that $a_n=0$ otherwise (except possibly when $n=-1$), we proceed by induction as follows:

Suppose there is some nonnegative integer $k$ such that, for all integers $m$ with $-2^{k+1}\le m\le-2^k-1,$ we have $a_m=0.$ (This clearly holds in the $k=0$ case.) Take any odd integer $m$ with $-2^{k+2}\le m\le-2^{k+1}-1.$ Since $m$ is odd, then in fact, $-2^{k+2}+1\le m\le-2^{k+1}-1.$ Moreover, $m=2j+1$ for some integer $j,$ so we have: $$-2^{k+2}+1\le 2j+1\le-2^{k+1}-1$$ $$-2^{k+2}\le 2j\le-2^{k+1}-2$$ $$-2^{k+1}\le j\le-2^k-1$$ Thus, $a_j=0$ by inductive hypothesis, so $a_m=a_{2j+1}=a_j=0.$

Now, suppose there is a positive integer $k$ such that, for all integers $m$ with $2^k\le m\le 2^{k+1}-2,$ we have $a_m=0.$ (This clearly holds for $k=1.$) Take any odd integer $m$ such that $2^{k+1}\le m\le 2^{k+2}-2.$ Since $m$ is odd, then in fact, $2^{k+1}+1\le m\le 2^{k+2}-3,$ and letting $m=2j+1,$ we have $$2^{k+1}+1\le 2j+1\le 2^{k+2}-3$$ $$2^{k+1}\le 2j\le 2^{k+2}-4$$ $$2^k\le j\le 2^{k+1}-2$$ Thus, $a_j=0$ by inductive hypothesis, so $a_m=a_{2j+1}=a_j=0.$

Letting $a_{-1}=k,$ we consequently find that $$f(z)=\frac{k}{z}+c\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{2^j-1}.$$ The series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{2^j-1}$ converges for $|z|<1,$ so $f(1)$ will be defined if and only if $c=0,$ in which case we would simply have $$f(z)=\frac{k}{z},$$ which is defined for all $z\ne 0.$

---

On the other hand, if we require $f$ to be defined at $0,$ we can either just use the Taylor expansion, say $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n,$$ then we'd instead have deduced that either $f$ is identically zero or $$f(z)=c\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{2^j-1},$$ which is defined for $|z|<1.$ However, the Laurent approach still works there: we simply determine that we need $k=0.$

---

**Upshot**: For any constants $c$ and $k,$ $$f(z)=\frac{k}{z}+c\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{2^j-1}$$ satisfies the given functional equation, and is defined for all $z$ such that $0<|z|<1.$ It will be defined at $z=0$ if and only if $k=0,$ and it will be defined for $z$ with $|z|\ge 1$ if and only if $c=0.$

Comment: Looks promising and rigorous, thanks!

Though, I have some trouble following after the first four equations. I think I understand that if I set $c=0$ and if I use Taylor I get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z^n-z^{2n+1})=0$ which by testing for different $n$ gives zero only for $n=-1$ and therefore a solutions would be $f(z)=a_{-1}z^{-1}=k/z$.

When you say that "let's suppose that $f(1)$ is ***not*** required", is that the same as $c=1$ and the solution $f(z)=k/z+c\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j$ is general with the constant $c$? If so, how do you derive that the summation must be included?

Comment: Also, using the Taylor expansion you deduced as $f(z)=c \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j$, I get with $z=1/2$ and $f(z)=c+zf(z^2)$ that $2 \neq c +c \cdot 2/3=c(1+2/3)$ which clearly isn't true for all $c$?

Comment: Apologies! I made a serious error in the series. It should be fixed now, and hopefully it's clearer why $c$ must be $0$ if and only if $f(1)$ is defined. Let me know if you have any other questions about my answer!

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer. Thank you very much for an extensive and rigorous answer! However, I still find it hard to understand how the coefficients are determined (the concept of series and all this is still very new to me). You seem to claim quite early on that $a_n=c$ if $n=2^j-1$, is there an intuitive explanation for this?

Comment: To figure that out, I just applied $$a_{2n+1}=a_n$$ to $a_0=c$ several times until I noticed a pattern: $$a_0=a_{2\cdot 0+1}=a_1,$$ $$a_1=a_{2\cdot 1+1}=a_3,$$ $$a_3=a_{2\cdot 3+1}=a_7,$$ $$a_7=a_{2\cdot 7+1}=a_{15},$$ and so on. I noticed that $0,1,3,7,15,...$ are all one less than a power of two, namely: $0=2^0-1,$ $1=2^1-1,$ $3=2^2-1,$ $7=2^3-1,$ $15=2^4-1,$ and so on. The induction proof that $a_{2^j-1}=c$ for all $j\ge0$ was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Another way is to notice that $1-0=1,$ $3-1=2,$ $7-3=4,$ $15-7=8,$ and so on. Thus, $1=0+1,$ $3=0+1+2,$ $7=0+1+2+4,$ $15=0+1+2+4+8,$ and so on. Put another way, $1=\sum_{i=0}^02^i,$ $3=\sum_{i=0}^12^i,$ $7=\sum_{i=0}^22^i,$ $15=\sum_{i=0}^32^i,$ and so on. Since we have in general that $$\sum_{i=0}^kx^i=\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}$$ whenever $x\ne 1$ and $k\ge 0,$ then using the $x=2$ case shows that $a_n=c$ whenever $n\ne 0$ and $n$ has the form $$n=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2-1}=2^{k+1}-1$$ for some integer $k\ge 0.$ Finally, we simply note that $0=2^0-1,$ so $a_n=c$ whenever $n=2^j-1$ for some $j\ge0.$

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so very much! I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $z = 1$ forces $c = 0$. Putting $g(z) = z f(z)$, we then have $g(z) = g(z^2)$. You haven't put any restrictions on $f$; but if it, say, has a Laurent series expansion near $z = 0$, then it's easy to see that $g$ must be constant, i.e., $f(z) = \alpha /z$ for some constant $\alpha$.

Comment: How does putting $g(z)=zf(z)$ give $g(z)=g(z^2)$? And what if $c \neq 0$, how would one go about to find the solution? Thank you!

Comment: For the former, just write down the original equation in terms of $g$. For the latter, the constant $c$ cannot be nonzero; put $z = 0$ in the original equation.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean with $g(z)=z \cdot f(z)=z\cdot z f(z^2)= z^2f(z^2)= g(z^2)$  if $g(z)=zf(z)$ and how that must mean that $g(z)$ is a constant. That seems reasonable. Although, wouldn't there be any circumstances where $c\neq0$? For example in a neighborhood other than $z=0$?

Comment: **If** we know *a priori* that $f(1)$ is defined, we can conclude that $c=0.$